# Can't remove unexpected reverse indents from flexbox cols with 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I don't understand, why I get this indents at the bottom:

[image: Unexpected indents]

I want to split row into cols of equal height, to make same height borders between cols. But somehow I get reverse indents. I don't use floats, so why they appeared? I need to write `height:100%`, because I need to have these borders. How to remove this bug and save the same height of cols? This is my code:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.row.no-gutters [class^='col-'],
.row.no-gutters .col {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

[class^='col-'],
.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.col-lg-3 {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
}

.feature {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 29px 0 0;
  padding: 8px 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.feature__h {
  margin: 26px 0 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 29.23px;
  color: #2e3035;
}

.feature__p {
  margin: 1px 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #828285;
}

.col+.col>.feature {
  border-left: 1px solid #2e3035;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
  </div>
  <!--.row-->
</div>
<!--.container-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the combination of `height: 100%` and `margin: 29px 0 0` on `.feature` that cause an overflow.

Assuming the margin were set so one can see the shadow, remove the margin from the `.feature` and instead add a bottom margin on the `.container`

*You also used `flex: 0 1 auto;` on `.feature`, though since its parent is not a flex container, it won't apply and were removed.*

Stack snippet

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  margin-bottom: 20px;                      /*  added  */
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.row.no-gutters [class^='col-'],
.row.no-gutters .col {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

[class^='col-'],
.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 26px;
}

.col-lg-3 {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
}

.feature {
  position: relative;
  /*flex: 0 1 auto;                             not needed  */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.feature__h {
  margin: 26px 0 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 29.23px;
  color: #2e3035;
}

.feature__p {
  margin: 1px 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #828285;
}

.col+.col>.feature {
  border-left: 1px solid #2e3035;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
  </div>
  <!--.row-->
</div>
<!--.container-->
```

---

Updated

Using `height: 100%` on `.feature` might cause you issue cross browsers, instead you could remove it and add `display: flex` to the `.col-lg-3`.

With this you take advantage of the flex "row" item's property `align-items`, which defaults to `stretch`, and will make the `.feature` equally high.

Stack snippet

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  margin-bottom: 20px;                       /*  added  */
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.row.no-gutters [class^='col-'],
.row.no-gutters .col {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

[class^='col-'],
.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 26px;
}

.col-lg-3 {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
  display: flex;                             /*  added  */
}

.feature {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.feature__h {
  margin: 26px 0 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 29.23px;
  color: #2e3035;
}

.feature__p {
  margin: 1px 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #828285;
}

.col+.col>.feature {
  border-left: 1px solid #2e3035;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col">
      <section class="feature">
        <h3 class="feature__h">feature 1</h3>
        <p class="feature__p">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--.feature-->
    </div>
    <!--col-->
  </div>
  <!--.row-->
</div>
<!--.container-->
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: @kizoso I made an update that you might want to consider.